# How to map one string into another in stream?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, filter, java-stream

I have a big problem with returning the following in-stream strings. Will you help?

Here is my list:

```
List<String> dest = Arrays.asList(
  "bleble bleble 2000",
  "WAW HAV 1200",
  "xxx yyy 789",
  "WAW DPS 2000",
  "WAW HKT 1000"
);
```

How can I return strings like this:

`//to HKT - price in EUR:    4300
//to HAV - price in EUR:    5160
//to DPS - price in EUR:    8600`

in on stream?

```
enter codedouble ratePLNvsEUR = 4.30;
List<String> result = dest
    .stream()
    .filter(x -> x.startsWith("WAW"))
    //.map() <- how to change "WAW HAV 1200" into "HAV - price in EUR:  5160"
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

for (String r : result) System.out.println(r);
```

This for (..) is required.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` to spli string, and get needed elements (second and third):

```
List<String> result = dest
        .stream()
        .filter(x -> x.startsWith("WAW"))
        .map(x -> {
            String[] row = x.split(" ");

            return String.format("to %s - price in EUR:    %s",
                    row[1],
                    Integer.parseInt(row[2]) * ratePLNvsEUR);
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: or `map(s->split(" ")).map(arr->String.format("to %s - price in EUR:    %s", row[1], Integer.parseInt(row[2]) * ratePLNvsEUR))`.

Comment: * I made simple copy-paste error in my previous comment. Instead or `arr` it should be `row` since that is how array was referred in `format`.